# Normal approximation to Binomial probability distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

[image]

[image]

Where did this 0.5 come from? I understand we are using Z-score but in my calculations I basically omit the 0.5 to get a probability of .9616.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the "continuity correction". You observe single units occurring, so you are in the middle of a value. Hence add or subtract 0.5 to actually switch to the next block and[image] make the result more appropriate.